# full screen and zoom in Koolplot

Tags: c++, mingw, graphing

I'm trying to graph some things in C++ and Koolplot seems like a very simple and suitable library to do so with. I'm stuck, however, on finding some documentation about it that allows me to fullscreen the application (or resize it like you can do so on lots of applications, chrome, word, discord...). As well as this, I can't find or see how i can allow the user to drag the graph around with the mouse as well as zooming into a point of a scatterplot or function. If anyone has any ideas about these things i'd appreciate it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The short reply is: cannot do.
Koolplot uses for drawings of the charts a modernized version of the venerable BGI driver. It was invented once upon a time, when personal computers were still running on some DOS version. Those times the graphics were full screen, hence of fixed size. This particularity was kept in the modernized WinBGIm library.
Zooming or panning properly a chart present on the screen require access from the drawing/painting routines of Koolplot to the data to be shown. This is not the case. If you look once again in the source code, you will note that in the implementation efforts were made to keep separated data to be plot from the actual drawing on the screen.
In conclusion, to do what you want, you will have to modify WinBGIm such that it manages correctly a drawing surface of variable dimensions and modify koolplot such that data to be shown is owned by (or aggregated with) Plotstream class.

Comment: That makes sense. With that, is there any libraries out there that you can sort of embed in c++ for graphing, such as like, you give it a range of data points or a function, and it graphs that, as well as zoom and movement?

Comment: For example, if I were to use SDL2, I could make a “graph” in the actual screen and interact with it, but i’d Have to make it from scratch, which I don’t really know how to do. @mtrif